# Does DisplayAlerts work in Word and PowerPoint when using automation?

Tags: c#, ms-word, powerpoint, office-automation

I have an app that processes Word, PowerPoint and Excel documents. After processing each document, I call the SaveAs method (or SaveAs2). For word, I set the DisplayAlerts to wdAlertsAll. I never see the dialog asking if I want to overwrite the document. I added code to get the alsert level right before calling SaveAs2 and it is wdAlertsAll. But, I see no message box. If I run Word and open the same file and do SaveAs to the same location as my app, the dialog appears.

I have the same issue with PowerPoint where I set the level to ppAlertsAll.

I do the same thing for Excel and ... it works just fine. I am prompted before doing the SaveAs.

In all three cases my app starts the Office apps and make sure they are visible on the desktop. I was thinking that perhaps running in the background was an issue but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

There's some MS documentation about DisplayAlerts in PowerPoint here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.displayalerts?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm502050)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

The writer should be complimented for his/her vivid imagination. It's all a fantasy, probably copy/pasted from the Excel docs. DisplayAlerts is part of the PPT object model but it's never worked.

For example, try this in VBA:

```
Sub BeAlert()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
    Debug.Print MsgBox("Testing", vbAbortRetryIgnore, "ArfArf")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsAll
    Debug.Print MsgBox("Testing", vbAbortRetryIgnore, "ArfArf")
End Sub
```

Both MsgBoxes appear, though the documentation suggests that only the second one will.

I'm not sure there'd be any difference between behavior in C# vs VBA, but in the latter, overwriting a file doesn't produce a message. It simply overwrites, no questions asked.

If you close a file that hasn't been saved since it was last changed, you may get a message; if you want to avoid that, set the presentation's .Saved property to True.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with open XML documents it makes sense to process documents without MS Office involved, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Otherwise, you can use the [Application.DisplayAlerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.displayalerts) in PowerPoint. The value of the `DisplayAlerts` property is not reset once a macro stops running; it is maintained throughout a session. It's not stored across sessions, so when PowerPoint begins, it is reset to `ppAlertsNone`.

```
Sub SetAlert
    Application.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not a macro. I am a separate executable. Apparently I have to be a macro as calling SaveAs with DisplayAlerts set to none does not prompt the user to overwrite the file (as Excel does).

Comment: Have you tried using Open XML SDK instead?